# Retrieving the URI and Collection Rel of an entity in Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

As the title says.  For context, although not terrible important, I'd like to trigger a WebSocket notification in the `AfterSave` event listener, and I'd like the resource or collection URI to correspond to the subscription endpoint.  Of course, I could hard code these values, but then I'm losing some benefit of using SDR.

So, does Spring offer a way to retrieve this information, the collection or entity URI, solely based off of the Object that the event listeners receive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do this by autowiring EntityLinks and then getting the link like this:

```
Link link = entityLinks.linkToSingleResource(MyResource.class, id);
String href = link.getHref();
```